# What's the keyboard shortcut to insert Horizontal line in Evernote?

Tags: windows, evernote

As question title says, what's the keyboard shortcut to insert horizontal line in Evernote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, I think that they will do what you are looking for.

Comment: Both aren't working..

Comment: Replacing Alt with Shift works...

Comment: @SachinShekhar, fixed, sorry

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+- works, thanks! Ctrl+h beings up Find in Note

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> inserts horizontal line.

Comment: I'd also add that it has to be the minus sign above the letter P.    The minus sign on the number pad doesn't work.  At least for me.